# Domains internall error and permanlink issue

Tags: wordpress

I have a hosting account on godaddy with 5 domains. They all are in **WordPress**. When I install **WordPress** on the primary domain then other domains shoot:

> 500 internal server error

especially when I set its **permalink** on `/%postname%`/.

Now permalink of primary domain is plain

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

try editing your `.htaccess` file with default `.htaccess` code

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I had the similar issue. This solved my problem.